# Storing Selected Input value on an array and inserting on mongodb

Tags: javascript, collections, meteor

So this is the problem
Actually i have this code, to insert a value from an Select

```
var valorTipoMenu =  document.getElementById('tipoMenu').value;
```

First i take the value from the select which id is 'restaurant', and later i take the value and insert on mongo collection like this,

```
Menu.insert({tipoMenu:valorTipoMenu});
```

so this work fine, but just insert 1x1 menu at time, so this is what im wanna do, i want to insert more than 2 values on `valorTipoMenu` variable, i think this may work like selecting one item from the select list, storing on and array variable called idk `manyMenus` , and later inserting that value on the mongo collection, but how can take the value from the select and storing on some array and later taking that array and inserting on mongo collection?

thanks regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different ways you can do this, but if you just want an array:

```
var valorTipoMenuArray = [];
valorTipoMenuArray.push(document.getElementById('tipoMenu').value);
valorTipoMenuArray.push(document.getElementById([NEXT ELEMENT YOU WANT TO PUT IN ARRAY]).value);
... MORE ELEMENTS ...
Menu.insert({tipoMenu: valorTipoMenuArray});
```